# How to use the primeNg picklist component in angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7, primeng, angular8

I am trying to use the PrimeNg picklist component.
I have two API, Roles and Users

User Api:

```
{
  "id": "U1",
  "username": "Baskar",
  "userRoles": [
                 {
                  "roleId": "R1"
                 },
                 {
                  "roleId": "R3"
                 }
                ]
 }
```

And model of User is like ,

```
export class User {
  constructor(
      public username: string
   ) { }
 }

export class userRoles {
   constructor(
       public roleId: string
    ) { }
  }
```

Role Api

```
[
 {
  "id": "R1",
  "name": "Warehouse Keeper"
 },
 {
  "id": "R2",
  "name": "Warehouse Manager"
 },
 {
  "id": "R3",
  "name": "Supplier"
 }
]
```

**Concept:**

**Available Value:** Get the roleId from Role Api and saved the values in the totalUsers variable. And assigned the totalUsers in Role[] (interface/model)

```
    totalRoles: Role[];
    this.roleService.getAllRoles().subscribe(userRoles => {
      this.totalRoles = userRoles;
    });
```

**Selected Value:**

```
   targetRoles : userRole[];

   this.targetRoles = [];
```

The code is like:

**TS:**

```
targetUsers : userRole[];
totalUsers: Role[];
ngOnInit(){
    this.roleService.getAllRoles().subscribe(userRoles => {
      this.totalRoles = userRoles;
    });
   this.targetRoles=[]
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p-pickList [source]="totalRoles" [target]="targetRoles" sourceHeader="Available"
        targetHeader="Selected" [responsive]="true" filterBy="brand" dragdrop="true" sourceFilterPlaceholder="Search by user"
        targetFilterPlaceholder="Search by user" [sourceStyle]="{'height':'300px'}" [targetStyle]="{'height':'300px'}">
        <ng-template let-role pTemplate="item">
          <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
            <div style="font-size:14px;float:right;margin:15px 5px 0 0">{{role.id}}</div>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
 </p-pickList>
```

Now Problem is,

I am able to select the available value and also can move it into right side. All picklist buttons are working. But the value is not displaying.

Values are selecting in UI, but sending null values to the server

Comment: did you print and check if there are values in targetRoles before sending it to server?

Comment: No values are sending to server.

Comment: But based on the primeNg document ,I did all steps. But not sending the selected values to the server